# onclick to get the content of Local notification generated from database android

Tags: android, database, notifications, local

I have generated multiple Local notifications by matching data from database.
Now i want that on clicking on the notification it will take to the particular products.

Code:----------

```
for (int i=0;i < alertList.size();i++) {
                Random random = new Random();
                int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
                msg=alertList.get(i).getProf_name()+" have to take "+alertList.get(i).getMed_name()+"                                                                                          ;"+alertList.get(i).getMed_id();
                Log.d("MediMSg",""+msg);
                Log.d("MediMSg",""+msg);
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MedicineNotificationActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("pushmsg",msg);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(MedicineNotificationActivity.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(100, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Test")
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setTicker("Notification from Test")
                        .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setColor(0x0091ea)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(m,notification);
                Log.d("Random",""+m);
            }
```